# Why doesn't this html code make a red div?

Tags: css, html

Why doesn't this code make red divs? I tried the same thing with an `h1` and it worked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            div {background-color:#f00;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What shape and size did you envisage the `div`s having, and why?

Comment: They are red, they just don't have any width since nothing is in them. Also did you try `h1`? Because if you created it like your `div`'s as in `<h1></h1>` the same thing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Because the DIVs need content (or a `height` setting) to have a height greater than 0 and therefore a visible background. Try to add some text...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            div {background-color:#f00;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here it is without content, but with a set `height`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            div {background-color:#f00; height: 20px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @LucasL, you can manually set the size of the div, then background color will be rendered.

Comment: @Sphinx which I wrote: "...or a height setting". The default width is 100%, so you don't need a width setting.

Comment: @Johannes, I know. I just want to show Lucasl the render result when size > 0.

Comment: @Sphinx but you should be precise, it's not "size > 0" (that doesn't even exist as a CSS property), it's "height > 0"

Answer (score 0):

As discussed; the divs need content or a height specified (divs are block level elements so will expand to fill the width to 100%) - rather than simply adding content - you can set the height with css. I also added a little style rule to show different colours on the odd ones.You could aslod use div:empty{} to target the empty divs if you are going to have some filled with content and some empty.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            div {background-color:#f00; height: 30px}
            div:nth-of-type(odd) {background-color: yellow}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```